# amp-form/amp-analytics tracking elements from form submit response

Tags: amp-html

I am trying to send a tracking tag that contains elements of the submission response on the success event.
So it would mean a tag that would look like this:

```
<amp-analytics type="atinternet">
<script type="application/json">
    {
        "vars": {
            "site": "SITE",
            "log": "LOG",
            "title": "TITLE",
            "level2": "LEVEL"
        },
        "triggers": {
            "formSubmitSuccess": {
                "on": "amp-form-submit-success",
                "request": "pageview",
                "extraUrlParams": {
                     "extraP": "${response.extraP}"
                }
             }
        }
    }
</script>
```

with a submission response that look like that: { "extraP" : "toto" }

Is it even possible?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: To clarify, you're hoping to be able to pass a form field value into the extraUrlParams variable? Is the field you're trying to get a pre-determined list of values (select menu, check boxes, or radio buttons) or user inputted data (text field)? I haven't used the extraUrlParams variable before, but the only way I could see this working is with amp-mustache and amp-state but I'm not sure they work with amp-analytics.

Comment: No, what i want to do is to include datas from form submission response in the tracking.I'm trying to use mustache but it doesn't seem to be compatible with amp-tracking.